# WordPress internal server error, when trying to include the stripe-php in my theme

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am trying to include stripe-php files in my theme, i have included this in function where the web-hook is listening.  Other actions performing without any error. But when i tried to call these files it throws me an error, Can anyone help me in this please.

````
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multibanco_payment_webhook', 'multibanco_payment_webhook'); 

add_action('wp_ajax_multibanco_payment_webhook', 'multibanco_payment_webhook');

function multibanco_payment_webhook(){

    $wp_strip_path = dirname( __FILE__ )."/multibanco/stripe/init.php";
    require_once($wp_strip_path);    
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_live_4zfLSISZXXjEqURCP0cbwRnT00d7pbro1X');
}
    ```
````

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error and stack you're seeing, as well as what steps you've taken to install stripe-php and any other related info?

Comment: For the above code.. It is 500

Comment: You likely need to [enable PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to see the details of what is actually occurring.

Comment: hi, found the solution, include path gone wrong. thank you.